# Hierarchy organizational unit bottom up approach

Tags: sql-server, design-patterns

I habe a organizational user management structure where a user for example `Level 5` in a position of an org unit is automatically in `Level 4, 3, 2, 1`.

As you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

Each org unit has it's own `ID` and each user as well. So I have an extra table where I store all `groupId<->userId` relations for each level. In this case I can just get all users e.g. from Level 3 because all users are related using the n:n table.

This way it is easy to query if a user is in a specified org unit but... it is complex to hold this structure consistent.

Example: If I remove a user from `Level 3/Employee` it also has to be removed from `Level 2`, but only from `Level 1` if this user is not in `Level B/Employee`.

So the question is.
As I can't change the way the user inherit the org units from bottom up is there a way or design pattern how to implement this approach with having the user only referenced once to his final location.

Example: I reference a user to `Level 5/employee` and this is persisted in the database, but I don't want to add relations for `Level 4 - 1`, but I still want to query fast if the user is e.g. in `Level 2`.

I don't want any detail codes, this is more a general design question because I want to redesign my user management to make it less error prone.
Fantastic would be also if I can query the data fast with SQL (e.g. CTE queries with MS SQL) but it should generally work in a MVC (using RoR) environment.

If someone need more details or information I will post ofc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I got many answers :) I did some more investigations and have a final approach now.

The answer is nested tree to perform fast queries.

What I did:

Create a user table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[actor_users](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [manager_id] [int] NULL,
    [deputy_id] [int] NULL,
    [username] [nvarchar](48) NOT NULL,
    [pwd] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [pwd_url] [char](38) NULL,
    [guid] [char](38) NULL,
    [deactivated] [smallint] NULL,
    [lastname] [nvarchar](48) NULL,
    [middlename] [nvarchar](48) NULL,
    [firstname] [nvarchar](48) NULL,
    [acronym] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
    [employee_nr] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
    [department] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [cost_unit] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
    [desc] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [email] [nvarchar](192) NULL,
    [sex] [int] NULL,
    [group_ids] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [picture_id] [int] NULL,
    [lcid] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [ct_actor_users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( [id] ASC ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Create a group table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[actor_groups](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [parent_id] [int] NULL,
    [group_name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [group_type] [int] NOT NULL,
    [group_reference] [int] NOT NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [depth] [int] NULL,
    [left] [int] NULL,
    [right] [int] NULL,
    [id_path] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [name_path] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [ct_actor_groups] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( [id] ASC ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I filled the user table with around 10k rows of random users.

Now I created some random tree

```
-- create some random tree for testing
DECLARE @id int;
DECLARE @name nvarchar(max);
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM actor_groups)<1000 
BEGIN
SET @id = (SELECT ISNull(MAX(id),0) + 1 FROM actors);
SET @name = 'random_ou' + CAST(NEWID() AS nvarchar(40));

INSERT INTO actor_groups (id, parent_id, group_name, group_type, group_reference, [description], depth, [left], [right], id_path, name_path) 
SELECT @id
  , (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM actor_groups ORDER BY NEWID()) AS parent_id
  , @name group_name
  , 3 group_type
  , -1 group_reference
  , '' [description]
  , 0 depth
  , 0 [left]
  , 0 [right]
  , '' id_path
  , '' name_path
END
```

After this I have to update the nested set relations....

```
-- update tree 
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM actor_groups WHERE depth IS NULL) 
UPDATE tr SET 
  tr.depth = par.depth + 1 , 
  tr.id_path = par.id_path + ',' + CAST(tr.id AS nvarchar(255)) , 
  tr.name_path = (CASE par.id WHEN 40 THEN '' ELSE par.name_path + '/' END) + tr.group_name
FROM actor_groups AS tr 
INNER JOIN actor_groups AS par ON (tr.parent_id = par.id) 
WHERE par.depth >=0 AND tr.depth IS NULL

GO

-- left, right nested set
WITH treerows AS
( SELECT actor_groups.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id_path) AS Row FROM actor_groups )

UPDATE actor_groups
SET [left] = tbl.Lft
  , [right] = tbl.Rgt
FROM actor_groups
JOIN (SELECT
  ER.id,
  ER.id_path,
  ER.depth,
  ER.Row,
  (ER.Row * 2) - ER.depth AS Lft,
  ((ER.Row * 2) - ER.depth) +
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) * 2
        FROM treerows ER2
        WHERE ER2.id_path LIKE ER.id_path + ',%'
    ) + 1 AS Rgt
FROM treerows ER
) tbl ON tbl.id = actor_groups.id
```

Now I did some random mappings...

```
-- do some random mappings
DECLARE @map int;
DECLARE @mapuser int;
DECLARE @counter int;
SET @counter = 1;
WHILE @counter<1000 
BEGIN
  SET @map = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM actor_groups ORDER BY NEWID())
  SET @mapuser = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM actor_users ORDER BY NEWID())
  INSERT INTO actor_mappings ([group_id], [user_id], imported) VALUES (@map, @mapuser, 0)
  SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END
```

So now I have a groups and a user table.
Users are filled with 10.000 users and my tree has around 1.000 nodes.
I did start the random mapping SQL several times, so I have around 100.000 mappings.

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      m.[user_id] AS luserid
    , org.[id] AS lgroupid
    , m.imported AS bimported
  FROM [test].[dbo].[actor_groups] org
  JOIN [actor_groups] org2 ON org2.[left] BETWEEN org.[left] AND org.[right]
  JOIN actor_mappings m ON org2.id = m.group_id
```

Query runs in around 700ms if I do not narrow it. Seeking for a special node or user is made in around 150-300ms on my tests.

**Resolution:**
This can be done using nested sets.

Updating the tree with my 1.000 nodes is made in like 1 second and query the data without any additional index on my tables is always below 1 second as well.

Hope this helps other people facing the same issue.